# A question regarding "DiscretizeGraphics"

Tags: graphics, computational-geometry, regions

I want to find the volume of a torus

```
torus =
 RevolutionPlot3D[{2 + Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

```
dtorus =
 DiscretizeGraphics[Cases[Normal @ torus, _GraphicsGroup, -1][[1]]]
```

[image]

The `Documentation` for `RegionMeasure` states:

> "RegionMeasure is also known as count (0D), length (1D), area (2D),
>   volume (3D)..."

```
{Area @ dtorus, RegionMeasure @ dtorus, Volume @ dtorus}
```

> {78.6557, 78.6557, 0}

Next, I want to find the volume of the torus' bounding cuboid

```
bounds = RegionBounds[dtorus]
```

> {{-3., 3.}, {-3., 3.}, {-1., 1.}}

```
cuboid =
  Graphics3D[{Green, Opacity @ 0.2, Cuboid @@ Transpose[bounds]}];

Show[torus, cuboid, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Now find the volume of the cuboid

```
dcuboid =
 DiscretizeGraphics @ cuboid
```

[image]

```
{Area @ dcuboid, RegionMeasure @ dcuboid, Volume @ dcuboid}
```

> {Infinity, 72., 72.}

**Questions**

How can it be that the `Volume` of the bounding cuboid, `72`, is lower than the "Volume" of the torus, `78 .6557`?

What do I overlook here?

What other options do I have to find the volume of my torus?

Comment: But isn't the volume of your torus 0?  `{Area @ dtorus, RegionMeasure @ dtorus, Volume @ dtorus}`->`{78.6557, 78.6557, 0}`. As I understand, RevolutionPlot3D plots a surface. A surface itself has 0 volume, for instance, a sphere.

Comment: @GregoryRut A sphere has volume 4/3 Pi * radius^3, hasn't it?

Comment: No, it's somehing different. A ball has a volume. You could define an interior volume of a sphere.

Comment: If you do `RegionDimension[dtorus]`, you'll see why. In this case `RegionMeasure` is giving you the surface area of the torus since you have a 2D region.

Comment: @RunnyKine Kind of pity that you didn't write your comment as an answer. My `dtorus` transformed a gentle three-dimensioal subject into dumb two-dimensional polygon-objects.

Comment: I guess I didn't have time to expand on it at the time. Maybe I'll do that and show more examples later.

Comment: If you do `RevolutionPlot3D[{2 + Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, Pi/2, 2 Pi}]` it should be clear that in general one cannot expect a `RevolutionPlot3D` to describe a volumetric object. http://i.stack.imgur.com/SJAhk.png

Comment: @RahulNarain, the truth is, `DiscretizeGraphics` will almost always give a surface discretization regardless of how the graphics was generated, which will result in a 2D region in general.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I have mentioned in my comment, in order to define a torus with a volume, you need an inequality. Just like you would define the interior of a sphere: $x^2+y^2+z^2<R^2$. The interior of the torus is defined by an inequality 
    $\left(R - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\right)^2 + z^2 < r^2 $, where R and r are the major and minor radii, respectively.

```
tor[R_, r_, x_, y_, z_] := (R - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])^2 + z^2 < r^2

Volume@DiscretizeRegion[
  ImplicitRegion[
   tor[2, 1, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}]
(*38.30219*)
```

The formula for interior volume of a torus reads $    V = 2 \pi^2 R r^2.$ In our case the volume would be roughly $V\approx $39.5.

It seems that `Volume` could be applied for 'derived regions' (like `tor`, for instance) yet it seems that it works only for selected types of areas.

Comment: Why do you use `6` instead of `2 Pi` ?  `2 Pi`would give `305.657`

Comment: There was an error with def. of `tor` function (`R^2` instead of `R`). It's fixed now. The range of variables has been modified as well.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not 100% sure on this, but I think you can construct a torus as a Cartesian product of a disk and a circle. Unfortunately you can't visualise it because the embedding dimension is 4, but the volume seems to come out correct:

```
Volume @ RegionProduct[Disk[{0, 0}, 1], Circle[{0, 0}, 2]]

(*  4 π^2  *)
```

or with symbolic radii:

```
Volume @ RegionProduct[Disk[{0, 0}, r], Circle[{0, 0}, R]]

(* 2 π^2 r^2 R *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Now we can set

```
Mesh -> None, Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" -> False}
```

Thanks @MichaelE2

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/92557/72111

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/226367/72111

```
torus2 = 
  RevolutionPlot3D[{2 + Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2  Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
   Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" -> False}, PlotPoints -> 60];
reg = torus2 // BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics
FindMeshDefects[reg]
Volume[reg]
```

[image]

> `39.3297`