# What Method values are available for Plot?

Tags: plotting, options, undocumented

The Documentation Center [article on `Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) notes under *Details and Options* that `Method` is one of the options for `Plot`.

However, it doesn't mention what `Method` values are allowed, and 
neither does the [article on `Method`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Method.html).

The *Options* section of the `Plot` article gives details on 91 options, 
but `Method` isn't one of them.

The more general problem I'm having: when I do `Plot[f[x], {x, a, b}]` 
for a certain function, `Plot` graphs it just fine, but spews out a ton 
of warnings that suggest `Plot` is trying to symbolically 
differentiate (or otherwise symbolically manipulate) my function, 
which is impossible since `f` is defined with `SetDelayed`.

To avoid these warnings, I want to tell `Plot` to only evaluate this function numerically and not attempt to find its derivative/etc.

Comment: Have you tried `f[x_?NumericQ] := ...`?

Comment: Probably, it's inheriting [the `Method` options of `Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html#1242255876), as well as the setting [`Method -> {"Refinement" -> {"ControlValue" -> (* radian angle *) }}`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8484) which is the direct equivalent of `MaxBend` in older versions.

Comment: Have you seen [How to find out which method Mathematica selected?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145/how-to-find-out-which-method-mathematica-selected)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one find undocumented options or option values in Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/809/how-can-one-find-undocumented-options-or-option-values-in-mathematica)

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69448/method-options-for-densityplot-and-contourplot

Answer (score 7):

Below are a bunch, although they seem to be a compilation of options for many or all plotting functions, including (mainly) 3D functions.  As @belisarius remarked in a comment, using [`?NumericQ`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037) is the standard way to prevent symbolic analysis, if indeed `Plot` is doing such.  Use something like

```
nf[x_?NumericQ] := f[x];
Plot[f[x], {x, a, b}]
```

Without a specific `f[x]` that reproduces the problem, it is impossible to check whether a particular "fix" will in fact work or even if the function is being differentiated. (3D plots often compute normals, but I have never noticed that any 2D plots that compute derivatives.)

`*Plot*` method options:

```
Charting`CommonDump`$VisualizationMethodOptions

(*   {"ScalingFunctions", "PlotRandomSeed", "DraftRendering", "ArrayPlot", 
"InvertNormalsDirection", "BoundaryOffset", "Refinement", 
"MeshBoundaryValues", "StepsJoined", "SurfaceStitch", 
"UnboundedPolygons", "InterpolateMesh", "DownsampleWindow", 
"FilterMeshAll", "OriginalCoordinates", "ReturnMeshObject", 
"ReturnRawMeshObject", "MeshMaxRecursion", "ContourMaxRecursion", 
"DelaunayDomainScaling", "PolygonReverse", "VertexAliasTolerance", 
"Average", "Fan", "Seidel", "Constrained", "GradientAligned", 
"MeshRegions", "PathPolygons", "SimplifyPaths", 
"PackGraphicsComplex", "SnapContourVertex", "PlotTheme", 
"VertexColorsPalette", "VectorBackgroundPadding", "ReturnImage", 
"Closed3DRegion", "PolygonColoring", "Equalized", "EqualizeColor", 
"ColorFunctionData", "Valence", "Laplace", "Conformal", 
"RGBColorSpace", "GrayColorSpace", "ParallelPlotEvaluate", 
"ParallelPlotMethod", "ParallelPlotParameters", "LightingMethod", 
"DiffuseReflection", "AspectBasedShading", "Contrast", "Brightness", 
"Saturation", "SpatialResolution", "ElevationDefault", 
"IlluminationModel", "AngularDistanceRadius", "UseNumericalFunction", 
"NumericalFunction", "FlattenFunctions", "SuppressMessages", 
"MessagesHead", "MappingFunctions", "DomainMappingFunctions", 
"LegacyColorFunctionProcessing", "ContourShadingPrefixFunction", 
"ContoursPrefixFunction", "UseCaching", "CutMeshLines", 
"FillBoundaryLines", "Ungroup", "CloseMeshThickness", 
"ClipNoneMeshShading", "ClipAtPlotRange", "ClipMeshOverlay", 
"ClipBoundaryLines", "Subdivision", "CellDecomposition", "Divisions", 
"ControlValue", "VertexTolerance", "MaxBoundaryEdgeLength", 
"CellCuboids", "Dihedral", "Gaussian", "GradientNorm", "Loop", 
"Contouring", "Curvature", "ContourLevel", "PlanarRectangular", 
"Triangular", "Quad", "QuadTriangular", "Length", "Area", 
"Perimeter", "BhatiaLawrence", "AverageNormal", "WeightedNormal", 
"Barycenter", "Cotangents", "Circumcenter", "Incenter", "Inradius", 
"Circumradius", "InteriorAngles", "Dual", "OFF", "NOFF", "Frenet", 
"NaturalNeighbour", "InverseDistance", "Kriging", "MaxMemoryUse", 
"Intersect", "FullLattice", "MarchingCubes", "AdvancedMarchingCubes", 
"AdaptiveTriangular", "Octree", "OctreeCubes", "Algebraic", 
"Cubical", "Tetra", "Seeds", "Linear", "Bisect", "NoiseDelta", 
"ContourSpacing", "MeshSpacing", "Quantile", "CurveLength", 
"ArcLength", "DataLineMesh", "DataPointMesh", "GraphicsIndex", 
"SymbolicPiecewiseSubdivision", "pw", "PiecewiseTimeConstraint", 
"SymbolicPointsTimeConstraint", "Singularities", "Isolated", 
"SingularCurves", "SingularMaxRecursion", "ExclusionsOffset", 
"PolygonReduction", "Polygons", "PolygonContraction", 
"PointPlacement", "QuadricWeighting", "CompactnessRatio", 
"MeshPenalty", "BoundaryWeight", "EndPoint", "EndOrMidPoint", 
"LinearPoint", "OptimalPoint", "UniformWeight", "AreaWeight", 
"AngleWeight", "AverageWeight", "AreaAverageWeight", "NormalWeight", 
"VerticesGoal", "EdgesDistanceGoal", "MinArea", 
"PreserveInteriorFaces", "SegmentPartition", "SegmentLengthGoal", 
"LegendsFunction", "Legend", "Extrapolation", "Interpolation", 
"PointsToSpheres", "Caps", "ConnectEnds", "StreamlinesMethod", 
"StreamlinesSamplingStep", "StreamlinesInsertionStep", 
"StreamlinesParameterLimit", "StreamlinesNDSolve", 
"StreamlinesNumericalFunction", "LICLines", "LICMinHits", 
"LICMaxLines", "AccuracyGoal", "PrecisionGoal", "HSBChannel", 
"LICModulate", "NewtonFlow", "PerturbateFrame", "PerturbateSeeds", 
"ParseGlyphStyle", "LinePath", "LineArrow", "GlyphPath", 
"Directional", "DirectionalScaled", "Velocity", "VelocityScaled", 
"ControlPoints", "BSplineCurve", "BezierCurve", "NURBSCurve", 
"XSplineCurve", "BSplineShape", "BezierShape", "NURBSShape", 
"XSplineShape", "SharedMemoryReference", "Method", "Automatic", 
"None", "All", "True", "False"}   *)
```