# Placing plot legend in front of the axes

Tags: plotting, legending

When I plot a function with legend and axes, the legend gets placed behind the axes (see example below)

---

[image]

---

I would like to have the legend sitting in front of everything. Is there a parameter that controls this? If not, what is the easiest way to accomplish this. I must emphasize that I'm generating many plots, and I would like to avoid long manual adjustments.

Code used to generate figure:

```
Plot[{Sin[a],Sin[a-2/3Pi],Sin[a+2/3Pi]},{a,0,4Pi}, PlotLegends->Placed[LineLegend[{"ia","ib","ic"}, 
LegendFunction->(Framed[#,BaseStyle->FontSize->8, Background->White, RoundingRadius->2, FrameMargins->None,
FrameStyle->Directive[Thin,Black]]&), Spacings->0.0, LegendMarkerSize->10],{{.99,.99},{1,1}}], 
ImageSize->180, AspectRatio->1/2]
```

"11.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)"

Comment: Do you get what you need if you add the option `Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}` to `Plot`?

Comment: @kglr that works on 11.3 on macos.

Comment: I did not try that method. It works. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a place where all 'Plot' methods are documented? I found [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/92557/34848) from @Michael E2, but it does not contain this particular method, which leads me to conclude that there might be some other methods not listed there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the option `Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}` in `Plot` gives (in version 9 / windows 10 - 64 bit):

[image]