# How to discretize a parametric polar surface ensuring the correct periodicity of the mesh

Tags: plotting, mesh

I am trying to discretize a polar surface using a combination of `ParametricPlot3D` and `DiscretizeGraphics`. Unfortunately, the mesh facets refuse to connect along the u=0, u=2Pi line. This is clearly shown by `FindMeshDefects`.

```
test = DiscretizeGraphics[
  ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u], Sin[u], v}, {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {v, 0, 1}, 
   PlotPoints -> {155, 20}, MaxRecursion -> 0, Mesh -> None, 
   MeshStyle -> None]]

test // FindMeshDefects
```

I know that specialized tools exist for surfaces of revolution, but this is meant to be just a minimal example. I also know of approaches using Implicit Regions, that I would like to avoid due to the bad quality of the meshing it produces.

I realize that the problem is due to the fact that `DiscretizeGraphics` computes distinct edges for u=0 and u=2Pi, yet I believe that it might be possible to identify said edges using a small distance criterion, yet I fail to do so algorithmically.

thanks in advance for the advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mesh = DiscretizeGraphics[
   ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u], Sin[u], v}, {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {v, 0, 1}, 
    PlotPoints -> {155, 20}, MaxRecursion -> 0, Mesh -> None, 
    MeshStyle -> None]];
```

Get a mesh connectivity graph and find candidate edges (or points):

```
g = MeshConnectivityGraph[mesh, {1, 1}, 2];

bcells = Pick[VertexList[g], VertexDegree[g], 2];

bpoints = 
  DeleteDuplicates[
   Flatten[MeshPrimitives[mesh, bcells][[All, 1]], 1]]; 

Graphics3D[Point[bpoints]]
```

[image]

Then find pair of points that are close each other:

```
nfunc = Nearest[bpoints];

prules = Rule @@@ 
   DeleteDuplicates[
    With[{p = nfunc[#, 2][[2]]}, 
       If[Norm[# - p] < 10^-5, Sort[{#, p}], Nothing]] & /@ bpoints];
```

And construct new mesh:

```
nmesh = MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[mesh] /. prules, 
  MeshCells[mesh, 2]];

FindMeshDefects[nmesh, "HoleEdges"]
```

[image]

You could make function to do this all together:

```
stitchMesh[mesh_, delta_:10^-5] :=
    Block[{g, bcells, bpoints, nfunc, prules},
        g = MeshConnectivityGraph[mesh,{1,1},2];
        bcells = Pick[VertexList[g],VertexDegree[g],2];
        bpoints = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[MeshPrimitives[mesh,bcells][[All,1]],1]];
        nfunc = Nearest[bpoints];
        prules = Rule@@@DeleteDuplicates[With[{p=nfunc[#,2][[2]]},If[Norm[#-p]< delta,Sort[{#,p}], Nothing]]& /@ bpoints];
        MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[mesh]/.prules, MeshCells[mesh,2]]
    ]
```

Comment: this is brilliant, it works on my non-axysimmetric surface, and it is also what I originally wanted to do, but couldn't quite wrap my head around. My question is 100% solved, thanks again

Answer (score 5):

The gap in the edge can be eliminated in the plot with the method option `”BoundaryOffset”`:

```
test = DiscretizeGraphics[
  ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u], Sin[u], v},
   {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {v, 0, 1}, 
   PlotPoints -> {155, 20}, MaxRecursion -> 0,
   Mesh -> None, MeshStyle -> None,
   Method -> “BoundaryOffset” -> False]]

test // FindMeshDefects
```

Comment: this works just as well as the other answers! Do you know where to find documentation on such Method options?

Comment: Many are undocumented. There are some Q&A on site that collect them, like this one, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/173431/4999

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
f = 1. + .5 Sin[4 Pi #] &;
ParametricPlot3D[{f[v] Cos[u], f[v] Sin[u], v}, {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {v, 
  0, 1}, PlotPoints -> {155, 20}, MaxRecursion -> 0, Mesh -> None, 
 MeshStyle -> None]
```

[image]

you can just do

```
f = 1. + .5 Sin[4 Pi #] &;
n = 155;
{x, y} = Transpose@Cases[
     Plot[f[v], {v, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 20],
     _Line,
     \[Infinity]
     ][[1, 1]];
m = Length[x];
\[Theta] = Most@Subdivide[0., 2. Pi, n];
pts = Join @@ Transpose[{
     Transpose[ConstantArray[x, Length[\[Theta]]]],
     KroneckerProduct[y, Cos[\[Theta]]],
     KroneckerProduct[y, Sin[\[Theta]]]
     },
    {3, 1, 2}
    ];
{q1, q2, q3, q4} = Transpose[getGridQuads[n + 1, m, True, False]];

R = MeshRegion[pts, Triangle[Join[Transpose[{q1, q2, q3}], Transpose[{q3, q4, q1}]]]]
```

[image]

where

```
getGridQuads = Compile[{
   {m, _Integer}, {n, _Integer},
   {xclosed, True | False}, {yclosed, True | False}
   },
  Block[{a1, a2, a3, a4, b1, b2, quads, qq, mm, nn},
   b1 = Boole[xclosed];
   b2 = Boole[yclosed];
   mm = m - b1;
   nn = n - b2;
   
   quads = Flatten[Table[
      qq = Table[
        a1 = mm (j - 1) + i;
        a2 = mm (j - 1) + i + 1;
        a3 = mm j + i;
        a4 = mm j + i + 1;
        {a1, a2, a4, a3},
        {i, 1, mm - 1}];
      
      If[xclosed,
       Join[qq,
        a1 = mm (j - 1) + mm;
        a2 = mm (j - 1) + 1;
        a3 = mm (j) + mm;
        a4 = mm (j) + 1;
        {{a1, a2, a4, a3}}
        ],
       qq
       ]
      ,
      {j, 1, nn - 1}], 1];
   
   If[yclosed,
    qq = Table[
      a1 = mm (nn - 1) + i;
      a2 = mm (nn - 1) + i + 1;
      a3 = i;
      a4 = i + 1;
      {a1, a2, a4, a3},
      {i, 1, mm - 1}];
    If[xclosed,
     a1 = mm nn;
     a2 = mm (nn - 1) + 1;
     a3 = mm;
     a4 = 1;
     qq = Join[qq, {{a1, a2, a4, a3}}]
     ];
    Join[quads, qq],
    quads
    ]
   ],
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
  ]
```

Comment: This code is Brilliant, yet, to my understanding it would only work for axisymmetric surfaces, is it correct? What can be done for non axysimmetric surfaces? The minimal example I provided was indeed axysimmetric, but I am interested into the parametrization of a similar surface for which I have a polar expression, but that is not a surface of revolution

Comment: Erm. You're question was about surfaces of revolution, right? Anyways, the compiled function can generate the quads for reactangle, cylinder, and torus topologies. So just get the vertex positions somehow and set the Boolean input variables as needed.

Comment: MY BAD, somehow while posting I was rolled back to the original (incorrect) title I had written, containing the word "surfaces of revolution" instead of polar. I will try to edit now, yet your compiled function is 200% useful.